# How to make ActiveRecord updates thread safe in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, activerecord, resque

I have a Resque queue of jobs. Each job has a batch of events to be processed. A worker will process the jobs and count the number of events that occurred in each minute. It uses ActiveRecord to get a "datapoint" for that minute and add the number of events to it and save.

When I have multiple workers processing that queue, I believe there is a concurrency issue. I think there is a race condition between getting the datapoint from the database, adding the correct amount, and updating to the new value. I looked into Transactions, but I think that only helps if the query would fail.

My current workaround is only using 1 Resque Worker. I'd like to scale and process jobs faster, though. Any ideas?

Edit: I originally had trouble finding key words to search Google for, but thanks to Robin, I found the answer to my question [here](http://www.alfreddd.com/2011/01/atomic-increment-in-rails.html).

The correct answer is to use `increment_counter` or `update_counters` if you need to increment multiple attributes or a value other than +1. Both of them are model classes.

Comment: If the only thing you need to be thread safe is the increment, could you use the `increment` method? Meaning that you wouldn't need the current datapoint. And doing something like `UPDATE events SET count = count + 42` is thread safe in mysql I think.

Comment: Thanks. I found [this](http://www.alfreddd.com/2011/01/atomic-increment-in-rails.html). The `increment` method is not thread safe. No custom SQL code is needed because `update_counters` generates essentially the same SQL.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't mean to use the raw SQL there. I just read somewhere that mysql was locking the table while performing this operation, so I thought it was thread safe.